# Fix vsync for Intel intergrated graphics (Debian-based Linux)

Tags: debian, drivers, intel-graphics

I'm getting Vsync tearing on videos using:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Read several close answers on here about installing a driver, that are very old and don't seem to work any more.
I do have this installed:

```
xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.99.917+git20200226-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I've added this repo: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/17.04/main

found one item that looks useful, but:

```
intel-graphics-update-tool : Depends: aptdaemon but it is not installable
                          Recommends: libproxy1-plugin-webkit (>= 0.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
```

So, is there any way to fix the Vsync tearing?
**UPDATE: I'm using Xfce**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xfce, you can disable overlay unredirection by toggling `/general/unredirect_overlays` (available since 4.3.99.1):

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/unredirect_overlays -T
```

For other readers using GNOME, the following fixes things for me there (based on [this comment on a GNOME bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741376#c15)):

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>
- enter `lg`
- enter `Meta.disable_unredirect_for_display(global.display)`
- press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit Looking Glass

Both of these cause full-screen windows, such as videos, to still go through the compositor, which enforces vsync.